# MariaDB cant change/ disable sql mode

Tags: mysql, sql, centos, mariadb

hi i need to disable strict mode in mariadb even adding via my.cnf  but its not working i did the following

```
SET sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

output and then i restared mariadb

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| sql_mode      |       |
+---------------+-------+

os : CentOs 7
db : maraidb 10.4
```

**update** even after adding in the my.cnf its not working getting this in ssh

```
mysql: unknown variable 'sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `my.cnf` file via SSH

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

Add following line in it

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

now restart MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

The error message is thrown by the command line client, since the variable sql_mode is a server variable.

To fix that, you have the following options:

1) If you have the permissions to edit the server configuration, and the sql_mode should be set for all connections, add the following to the server section of my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

2) If you want to enable it by client, add the following line in the client section of your my.cnf

```
[mysql]
init-command=SET SQL_MODE="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```